# Phase 10 not enough cards after skip card

Tags: phase-10

**2 players, phase 6 (1 run of 9) :**

Cards player 1: skip, skip, skip, 2, 4, 5, 7, 0, 5, 3

Player 1 decides to lay down a skip card.
Player 2 has to skip the turn.
Player 1 decides to lay down a skip card.
Player 2 has to skip the turn.
Player 1 lays the last skip card.
Player 2 has to skip again.

Player 1 now can never win because they don't have enough cards (7) to make a phase?

Comment: If you need to make a run of 9; you need 9 cards, not 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be under the incorrect assumption that you don’t draw a card on turns that you play a skip card. It doesn’t work that way; you start every turn by drawing a card.

So in your example, before each time that Player 1 plays a skip card; they would first draw a card. So the total number of cards in your hand never changes until you make your phase; it will always be 10, or 11 while in the middle of your turn.

[Rules:](http://www.tactic.net/site/rules/FIN/03140.pdf)

> PLAY: The player to the left of the dealer plays first. Play continues in a clockwise direction. **On your turn, draw one card, either the top card from the draw pile or the top card from the discard pile, and add it to your hand.** End your turn by discarding any one of your cards onto the top of the discard pile.